# Is there a reason phase information isn't given for RF wideband amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I have an application where I would like to amplify a HF signal (25 MHz) by around 20dB.  The signal can't be inverted (it sits within a PLL loop where the phase is important).  I considered building my own, but then I figured this component ought to be fairly common and will be much better than anything I'd build myself, with everything on a small die.

I checked the datasheets of many wideband mmic amplifiers offered by my local distributor and I noticed that none of them actually said whether the amplifier was inverting or not.  I suspect that most are based on some kind of collector feedback arrangement (common for RF amplifiers) but I can't be sure.  That would make them inverting.

None of the datasheets I examined offered non-inverting as a distinguishing feature, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious?  I realize I could cascade two low attenuating amps together, but that's a bit of a pain.  A quick search on the internet threw up the NE5205, but like many RF components it seems to have gone the way of the dodo.  Is there a reason phase isn't important or relevant in RF wideband amps and what do you do when you require a non-inverted signal?

Comment: For what its worth, looking through the minicircuits catalog, a lot of their RF amplifier datasheets include the equivalent transistor circuit, so it isn't unheard of.  Presumably if they decide to include it depends on the expected application.

Comment: @user1850479 I didn't target a particular vendor in my search. Instead, I just selected DC to whatever wideband amps with my local distributor and picked the top n choices before the prices escalated.  Most of those were BGAXXXX types.  I'll check mini-circuits to see whats on offer.

Comment: RF amplifiers can often be transformer coupled which makes restoring phase trivial.

Comment: @Brian Drummond That's a good comment.  Why not make it a formal answer with a quick schematic?

Comment: 25 MHz and 20 dB gain is fully in the reach of many op-amps these days.